# equivalent definition of approximately inner automorphism on a $C^*$- algebra

Tags: group-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose $A$ is a $C^*$-algebra,an automorphism $\alpha$ on $A$ is called approximately inner if for every finite subset $F$ of $A$ and for every $\epsilon > 0$,there is an inner automorphism $\beta$ on $A$ such that $\|\alpha(a)-\beta(a)\|<\epsilon$ for all $a\in F$.

There is a proposition:If $A$ is separable and if $\alpha$ is an automorphism on $A$,then $\alpha$ is approximately inner iff there exits a sequence $\{\alpha_n\}$ in $Inn(A)$ such that $\alpha_n(a)\to \alpha(a)$ for all $a\in A$.

$\Longleftarrow$, for any finite set $F$ of $A$,since there exits a sequence $\{\alpha_n\}$ in $Inn(A)$ such that $\alpha_n(a)\to \alpha(a)$ for all $a\in A$.we can take $\alpha_{n_0}$ such that $\alpha_{n_0}(a)\to \alpha(a)$ for  any $a\in F$

How to prove the right direction $\Longrightarrow$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $\{a_n\}$ be a countable dense subset of $A$.  For each $n\in\mathbb N$, there is an inner automorphism $\beta_n$ such that
$$\|\alpha(a_k)-\beta_n(a_k)\|<\frac1n$$
for $1\leq k\leq n$.

Comment: Is my thought correct:since $\{a_n\}$ is dense in $A$,for any $a\in A$,for any $\epsilon > 0$,there exists $N$ such that $\|a-a_N\|<\epsilon$,then $\|\alpha(a)-\beta_n(a)\|=\|\alpha(a)-\alpha(a_N)+\alpha(a_N)-\beta_n(a_N)+\beta_n(a_N)-\beta_n(a)\|$.

Comment: That's correct.